# -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
self.itemHeadingLabel = [[ShimmeringLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 182, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
```

when it enter into the library file ,it gets crash

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self initializeLayers];
}
return self;
```

}

It crashes after the line:- `self = [super initWithFrame:frame];`

Comment: check if your frame is nil.

Comment: `CGRect` is not an object. But it might have an invalid value.

Comment: @Nimmy Please copy the compete stack trace.

Comment: self.itemHeadingLabel = [[ShimmeringLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 182, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
    self.itemHeadingLabel.text = @"Now See the Action";
    self.itemHeadingLabel.tint = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.itemHeadingLabel];

Comment: @implementation ShimmeringLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 if (self) {
  // Initialization code
  [self initializeLayers];
 }
    //[self initData];
 return self;
}

Comment: @FawadMasud : frame is not nil.It have the cgrect value